# preg_match_all but stop if wildcard contains a slash

Tags: php, regex

Assuming I have this regular expression: `'#artists/(.*)/#'` and I want to match this string: `'/artists/alesana/wires-and-the-concept-of-breathing/'` how can I make sure that it only matches `'alesana'` and not `'alesana/wires-and-the-concept-of-breathing'`.

So in other words, how can I let my reg exp cohere to the slashes.
Technically I am gonna make another routing rule for `artists/(.*)/(.*)` but I know I'm gonna run in this problem somewhere else sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the regular expression non-greedy with the `?` character. This will essentially find the shortest match possible:

```
/artists/(.*?)/
```

Read more: [Lazy quantification in regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification)

Comment: Ahh.. I knew it would be something 'simple'. Let's hope I won't make this mistake anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you try this? `artists/[^/].+?/`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution than to use the non-greedy search as Hans Engel mentioned would be:

```
/artists/([^/]*)/
```

Using a `^` inside a  character class `[]` negates the content. Thus will `[^/]` match all characters BUT a slash.

You can read more about regular expressions and meta characters at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: You really want to avoid greedy operators in favor of non-greedy ones. Greedy operators tend to consume significantly more performance while evaluating.

Comment: Even though that's true in many situations that's not case here. Using a lazy quantifier in this case would actually result in much more operations than with a greedy, because of all the backtracks needed.